# trouble with netmask obtained from udhcpd

Tags: dhcp, busybox, netmask

I'm trying to use udhcpd, a dhcp server in busybox, to obtain IP adress.
I'm working on an ARM plateform with a standard linux on it.

The dhcp client IP address is ok, according to range setted in the udhcpd.conf file but the netmask is set to 255.255.255.255.
If I change it manually to 255.255.255.0, services works perfectly but I don't understand why netmask is set to this and what can be modified to make it automatic.

the (simple) conf file:

```
# Sample udhcpd configuration file (/etc/udhcpd.conf)
# Values shown are defaults

# The start and end of the IP lease block
start           192.168.7.2
end             192.168.7.254

# The interface that udhcpd will use
interface       usb0

option          subnet  255.255.255.0 (tested with or without this option)
```

Hope someone could help me undertand what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the source of the problem...
I was editing the .conf file with gedit and it puts a caracter like '^M' at the end of line. I could see this and fix it using VI tool.
So it was not understandable for udhcpd.